# Which alert would be displayed if there're many competing alerts?

Tags: ios, uikit, uialertcontroller

In iOS, many alerts can occur at a time in practice.

For example, if you're requesting a Photo Album (or whatever) permission, OS will present an alert. At a same time, programmer can `UIViewcontroller.present()` an `UIAlertController` instance as at their will.

What alert would be chosen at first place in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the internal implementation, but according to my experiment on iOS 10.1.1 real device, alerts are shown in this order.

1. System alerts. Alerts that presented by operating system itself. (such as Photo Album permission request) This is the highest priority. If any of this alert gets presented, any other in-app alerts will be **hidden** temporarily, and shown again after end-user make a choice on the system alert. Priority between system alerts are unknown.
2. Your in-app alert. You can present only one in-app alert at a time because you are supposed to use `UIViewController.present` method to present an alert in current version of iOS. And this method will use your nearest presentation-context VC or root VC of its window. In either case, Apple is actually enforcing you to present only one alert at a time, and control presentation priority of the alerts yourself.